# CoffeeScript execute functions from string with parameters

Tags: javascript, forms, coffeescript

I have in my html something like this:

```
<input type="text" data-validators="length(5,25);notNull();links(1);" />
```

Functions: length, notNull and links are in my Validation class.
I am getting these functions with jQuery

```
  $(this).find('[data-validation]').each ->
    validatorsString = $(this).attr "data-validation"
    validatorsArray = validatorsString.split ";"
    validatorsObject = new Validation($(this).val())
    for v in validatorsArray
      if typeof validatorsObject[v] == "function"
        validatorsObject[v]
```

This works fine when I dont use parameters (arg1, arg2) but now I want to use parameters.
How to check if these functions exists in class and execute it with paramters (with no limits, it can be 1, 5, 10 params)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't dynamically call functions with arguments as strings (unless you use `eval`), the best method to achieve the functionality you want you'll have to parse your `data-validation` information:

given this string: `validatorsString="length(5,25);notNull();links(1);"`, you could parse it into function names and arguments using a regular expression:

```
validatorsString.replace(/([\w_$]+)\(([\w_$,]+)\)/g, (all, fn, args) ->
  args = args.split ',' if args
  if typeof validatorsObject[fn] is 'function'
    validatorsObject[fn].apply validatorsObject, args
)
```